# c++ strtok segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++

I get segmentation fault (core dumped) when I run this code.

```
char firstAns[80], secondAns[80];
int rs, ansLen, pipefd[2];
int pid1, pid2;
char *command1[5];
char quit[] = "quit\n";
//Asking for the commands
cout << "Please enter your first command(incl. args) or quit: ";

fgets(firstAns, 80, stdin);
//Do the program while the first answer isn't quit
if(strcmp (quit,firstAns) != 0) {
int i = 1;
command1[0] = strtok (firstAns," ");
while (command1 != NULL) {
    command1[i] = strtok (NULL, " ");       
    i++;
}
```

Not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (command1 != NULL)
```

is almost certainly not what you wanted to do - `command1` will *never* be NULL/zero because it's on the stack.

I think your loop would be better written as:

```
int i = 0;
command1[i] = strtok (firstAns, " ");
while (command1[i] != NULL)
    command1[++i] = strtok (NULL, " ");
```

This will check the correct items (the return value from the most recent `strtok`) and leave `i` as the number of words stored.

I'd also consider making it a little more robust. As it stands now, entering five words or more will result in undefined behaviour as you write to `command1[5]` when the allowed indexes are `0` through `4` inclusive.